# The usage of "using"

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I wrote:

> A treebank may be created for a specific purpose **using** a specialized **annotation scheme**.

I couldn't find another word to relate the "treebank", which is a linguistic corpus, to the "annotation scheme", which is a model for annotating sentences.

First, what is the proper preposition? Can "using" be used in such cases? or it just should be in cases where we really use something to do something?

Comment: You can "use" a tool, an algorithm, a methodology, so "using" is fine, I think.  Alternatives are "by means of", "with the help of", "applying", "based on", etc.

Comment: @VictorBazarov I think here, "based on" suits more.

Answer (score 1):

"Using" is fine. "With" would also work, but "using" is really preferable.